# Smart home application

Tags: user-interface, automation, dashboard, alarm

I'm planning to code a **smart home application** for touch sensitive windows 10 tab (already I have) which can hang in wall.

I need:
Weather API data viewer, Alarm manager, Scheduled music player for morning and evening, Google calendar synced event viewer, Arduino sensor reading (home temp and humidity) .

I tried and designed a interface using C# and WPF. But my goal couldn't reached due to sorted issues below. [See attached image.][image]

C# - Not enough support for UI. No transparent/ no curve buttons /etc.

WPF - Less supportive for some extension and discontinued product.

ASP.Net - Less knowledge and I believe mp3 player and other extra sensor readings will not success through this.

So I need to know is there any specific softwares for designing Windows os smart home applications. Please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Flutter or Electron.

Flutter was designed by google it is opensource and runs on all operating systems.
I think it uses dart as a main language.

Electron on the other hand uses mostly HTML, CSS and Javascript. But it should be easier to design the user interfaces. For example Discord and VS Code were built using Electron.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your sharing. I tried Flutter as a beginner. Felt it required lot of dependencies. Electron even not tried due to less knowledge of Java. Can you give a suggestion for all in one tool like Visual studio. It's okay to install few extensions.  Or alternative option for WPF.

Comment: Hi,
first thing - electron is in javascript not java as you wrote(they are not the same).
Only other platform/library I have heard about is Qt. It uses C++ but can be switched to C, Python and other languages. More information here: https://www.qt.io/.
If you do not like it just google Electron alternatives and you can choose which one you want.